# When extending a class in TS using class decorators, how should I consume the extended class properties?

Tags: typescript

This is my class decorator that returns a new class

```
const ClassDecorator = (name: string) => {
    console.log(name);
    return <T extends new (..._: any[]) => { id: string }>(
        originalConstructor: T
    ) => {
        return class extends originalConstructor {
            newID: string;
            constructor(..._: any[]) {
                super();
                console.log('new constructor');
                this.newID = `${this.id}-${name}`;
                this.newMethod = this.newMethod.bind(this);
            }
            newMethod() {
                console.log('this is a new method');
            }
        };
    };
};
```

I am accepting the original constructor and extending it to include

```
newID
newMethod
```

On consuming the @ClassDecorator

```
@ClassDecorator('Mad-Maximilan')
class Person {
    id: string = 'SECRET';
    constructor() {
        console.log('Class Instantiated'); // 5
    }
}

const foo = new Person();
console.log(foo);
per.newID;
```

TSC complains that `newID` is not available in `foo`
object.

`newID` is available during runtime as expected.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, decorators cannot change the type of what they decorate (as of TypeScript 4.3.2).

See [TypeScript#4881](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) for  a lot more discussion and context.

One option is to a create type for your added fields:

```
interface WithClassDecorator {
  newId: string
}
```

And extend the class type with it after declaration:

```
@ClassDecorator('Mad-Maximilan')
class Person {
    id: string = 'SECRET';
    constructor() {
        console.log('Class Instantiated'); // 5
    }
}

// Open the `Person` class interface and extend it with the decorator added fields.
interface Person extends WithClassDecorator {}

const foo = new Person();
console.log(foo);
foo.newId; // works
```